# How to store data in Jetpack Compose Desktop?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I am creating an application in Jetpack Compose **Desktop** which will take user input and after user reopens the application that input value should be there. I mean a user given data should be there after user reopens the application.

```
remember { mutableStateOf } doesn't work here
```

I didn't get tag for jetpack compose desktop so I have android Jetpack Compose tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `remember` will only save data while the current view is visible on the screen. Check out more about state it compose in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).

If you need to save something between application runs, you need to save it to a database or write it to a file and read it when the application runs.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this is to use the Java `Preference` API to store Key/Value based values.

If you need more complicated data, you would need to store your data into a `File` or a database.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `java preferences`.

```
class Preferences {
    private val preferences: Preferences = Preferences.userRoot().node(this::class.java.name)

fun storeData(key: String, value: String) = preferences.put(key, value)
fun getData(key: String): String? = preferences.get(key, null)
fun deleteData(key: String) = preferences.remove(key)
```

}

Answer (score -2):

you need use sqlite or file to cache data, "remember" just cache to the running memory

Comment: Please don't repeat answers